# How can I set subfolder to a diffrent root location on nginx is i dont have a domain name?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I tried to set a server using nginx. I have set the public directory to var/www. Here I have 2 folder 1 for main website  with the name domain.com and 1 for development with the name dev.

Here is my config conf.d/domain.com.conf:

```
server{                                                                                                                                                                      
 listen 80 default_server;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 include /etc/nginx/defaul.d/*.conf;                                                                                                                                                           
 client_max_body_size 50M;                                                                                                                                                   
 root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;                                                                                                                                                    
 location /{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 }                                                                                                                                                                                              
 location ~ /\.ht {                                                                                                                                                                                    
  deny all;                                                                                                                                                                             
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
location ~* \.php$ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;                                                                                                                                                      
 include fastcgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                       
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;                                                                                                                             
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                             
location ^~ /dev {                                                                                                                                                                        
 alias /var/www/dev/$1;                                                                                                                                                            
 index index.php;                                                                                                                                                                             
 location ~* \.php$ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;                                                                                                                                                      
  include fastcgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                       
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_uri;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                             
location ^~ /pma {                                                                                                                                                                     
 auth_basic "Restricted";                                                                                                                                                                      
 auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_caf_pass;                                                                                                                                                 
 index index.php;                                                                                                                                                                           
 location ~ /\.ht {                                                                                                                                                                               
  deny all;                                                                                                                                                                                  
 }                                                                                                                                                                                             
 location ~* \.php$ {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;                                                                                                                                                      
   include fastcgi_params;                                                                                                                                                                       
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;                                                                                                                             
 }                                                                                                                                                                                     
 }                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

pma is from phpmyadmin and i have in my domain.com/public_html link to pma so this is working, the problem is with the dev folder when I try to access it i get 404 Not Found, if i try index.php i get the message "File not found.". If i access diffrent php filename the url will change to:

For example if i try admin.php the url will be: my_ip/dev/dev/admin.php, it should be my_ip/dev/admin.php

Comment: I think your `alias /var/www/dev/$1;` should be `root /var/www;` if your files are under `/var/www/dev/` as `dev` is already part of the URI and `$1` is undefined.

Comment: I still get 404 Not Found, and for index.php i get the message "File not found.".

Comment: Show the entries in the access log and error log, and the exact pathname of the file that's not found.

Comment: current path for dev/index.php in error log is /var/www/domain.com/public_html/dev/index.php